# angular ui-router $stateProvider states iterate through object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have been trying to dynamically populate the navbar from my states configured in $stateProvider. when i try to get the state name or the url or any other properties I get undefined, I have been using the $state.get()  but I could not find any example where kind of explain it how to use to iterate through states

Just for clarity and an example lets use the bellow states, I need to be able to dynamically generate the navbar with the states name (main, home, about)

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/states/main/main.html'
  })
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/states/main/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'home'
  })
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'app/states/main/about/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
```

see the implementation of the controller its probably nonesense

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.controller('NavBarController', NavBarController); 
function NavBarController($scope, $state) {
   var states = $state.get();
    angular.forEach(states, function (value, key) {
        // value returns [Object Object];
        // key returns numbers from 0 to 3
        console.log('get states ----   ')
    });
}
```

Comment: where is the state coming from? if it is get() who set() the value?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, `console.log(state.name)` to get the names of each state and accordingly other stuffs?

Comment: Is your controller attached to the module? From the code that you have shown, it does not seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

`$state.get()` return an [**array**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategetstatename) while `for ... in` [iterates over **properties** in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

You should use [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) instead:

```
// Get all state config objects
var states = $state.get();

// Loops through each state in states
// "value" is each state config object
angular.forEach(states, function(value, key) {
  // Log each state name
  console.log(value.name);
});
```

Comment: I editted my answer to clarify it. You can use `console.log(value)` to learn more about the state config object.